# How does historical data from bloomberg interact with timezones?

Tags: fixed-income, time-series, bond, fx, bloomberg

I'm running analysis on multiple countries bonds over a long stretch of time. I was asked about what determines the date of data in Bloomberg, ex: December 31st in NY will be January 1st in Japan and Australia, and I need to know if Bloomberg accounts for that. Does anyone have experience with this problem/question? I'm just trying to determine if I need to offset by a day to account for this.

Comment: You can ask the hell desk (F1F1).

Comment: Help desk, sorry for the typo. They aren't that bad after all.

Comment: Trust but verify. Ask the Help Desk first, but then check what they told you by looking up the closing price of an australian security a few days ago (from an independent source such as an exchange web site) and verifying that Bbg GP gives the correct price for that day. A misunderstanding here can ruin an entire research project.

Comment: Bloomberg related questions should always be referred to the helpdesk first.

Answer (score 1):

For desktop APIs like BDP, BDH etc it expects the local time that is setup on your terminal.

For programming APIs (i.e python, C++, COM Data control etc) you have to provide input dates and times in UTC standard regardless of where you are located and it returns in the same format.

bbg developers guide
https://data.bloomberglp.com/professional/sites/10/2017/03/BLPAPI-Core-Developer-Guide.pdf

Comment: SInce it depends how the data was retrieved (desktop API vs programming API) and in the case of local time on the ID that was logged on (two users will get different data!), it is a good idea if you create a data file to DOCUMENT IN THE DATA FILE ITSELF the time convention that is used. For ex. 2023-12-15 EST GOOG 133.84 (And, again, to verify with realtime data from a day or 2 ago).